# Google Ads Scripts: Can't Create A Blob Of CSV String. Unexpected error while getting the method or property newBlob on object Utilities

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I've been working on this google ads script to email a csv to me.
It queries the ad words api for data, writes it to a spreadsheet, reads it from the spreadsheet, iterates through the rows to create a csv string, creates a blob and sends the email.

The reason it writes/reads to a spreadsheet is to get the data in the correct format. I'm not sure there is a better way.

The problem is that it will not create the blob. It fails with this error:

```
Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property newBlob on object Utilities. (line 53)
```

I've looked online and can not find much on this error. I've tried removing arguments on the newBlob statement, sending the raw csv string, etc. Nothing seems to work and I can't figure out why creating the blob fails.

```
const SS_ID = '1_super_secret_id_Q';
const SS_NAME = 'GCLID Report';
const SHEET_NAME = 'DURING YESTERDAY'
const EMAIL_TO = 'c_super_secret_email_g'

const MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

function collect_report() {
  return AdsApp.report(
    'SELECT                ' +
    '  click_view.gclid,   ' +
    '  segments.date,      ' +
    '  customer.id,        ' +
    '  ad_group.id,        ' +
    '  campaign.id         ' +
    'FROM click_view       ' +
    'WHERE segments.date DURING YESTERDAY'
  );
}

function calculate_yesterday() {
  var now = new Date();
  var yesterday = new Date(now.getTime() - MILLIS_PER_DAY);
  var timeZone = AdsApp.currentAccount().getTimeZone();
  var yesterday_str = Utilities.formatDate(yesterday, timeZone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  return yesterday_str;
}

function convert_sheet_to_csv(sheet) {
  var csv_data = '';
  
  // This represents ALL the data.
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  // This logs the spreadsheet in CSV format.
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    csv_data += (values[i].join(',')) + '\r\n';
  }
}

function main() {
  var report = collect_report();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SS_ID);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  
  sheet.clearContents();
  report.exportToSheet(sheet);

  var mime = 'text/plain'
  var yesterday_str = calculate_yesterday();
  var filename = 'gclid_report.csv';
  var csv_data = convert_sheet_to_csv(sheet);
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(csv_data, mime, filename);


  var email_subject = 'Your Google Ads Report Is Ready: GCLID Report';
  var email_body = 'Attached is the ' + filename;

  MailApp.sendEmail(
    EMAIL_TO,
    email_subject,
    email_body,
    {
        name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
        attachments: [blob]
    }
  );
}

main();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your script, it seems that the function `convert_sheet_to_csv` returns no value. By this, `csv_data` of `var csv_data = convert_sheet_to_csv(sheet);` is undefined. I thought that this is the reason for your current issue of `Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property newBlob on object Utilities.`. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, `convert_sheet_to_csv` is modified as follows.

```js
function convert_sheet_to_csv(sheet) {
  var csv_data = '';
  
  // This represents ALL the data.
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  // This logs the spreadsheet in CSV format.
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    csv_data += (values[i].join(',')) + '\r\n';
  }
  
  return csv_data; // Added
}
```

- By this, `csv_data` of `var csv_data = convert_sheet_to_csv(sheet);` has the string value. And, `var blob = Utilities.newBlob(csv_data, mime, filename);` works.

Comment: Accepting this solution. Implementation worked and I have received the email I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as I've further optimized the code and it no longer requires a Google Sheet. Now, it can also take more than one recipient.

```
// Report settings
const REPORT_NAME = 'GCLID Report';
const EMAIL_TO = ['user@email.org'];
const EMAIL_FROM = 'Automatic Emailer Script';
const EMAIL_SUBJECT = 'Your Google Ads Report Is Ready: ' + REPORT_NAME;
const EMAIL_BODY = 'Attached is the ' + REPORT_NAME;

// File settings
const YESTERDAY_STR = calculateYesterday();
const FILE_MIME_TYPE = 'text/plain';
const FILENAME = 'gclid_report_' + YESTERDAY_STR + '.csv';

const REPORT_QUERY = `
  SELECT
    click_view.gclid,
    segments.date,
    customer.id,
    ad_group.id,
    campaign.id
  FROM click_view
  WHERE segments.date DURING YESTERDAY
`
// Collects the report for the previous day
function collectReport() {
  return AdsApp.report(REPORT_QUERY);
}

// Calculates yesterday's date string
function calculateYesterday() {
  const millis_per_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  const now = new Date();
  const yesterday = new Date(now.getTime() - millis_per_day);
  const timeZone = AdsApp.currentAccount().getTimeZone();
  return Utilities.formatDate(yesterday, timeZone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}

// Converts report rows into CSV format
function reportToCsv(report) {
  const rows = report.rows();
  const csvRows = [];
  
  // Creates CSV headers
  const first_row = rows.next();
  const columns = Object.keys(first_row).filter(column => column !== 'formatForUpload');
  
  // Creates CSV first row
  const values = columns.map(column => first_row[column]);
  csvRows.push(values.join(','));
  
  // Creates CSV remaining rows
  while (rows.hasNext()) {
    const row = rows.next();
    const values = columns.map(column => row[column]);
    csvRows.push(values.join(','));
  }

  return columns.join(',') + '\r\n' + csvRows.join('\r\n');
}

// Sends an email with the report attached
function main() {
  const report = collectReport();
  const csvData = reportToCsv(report);

  const blob = Utilities.newBlob(csvData, FILE_MIME_TYPE, FILENAME);

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: EMAIL_TO.join(','),
    subject: EMAIL_SUBJECT,
    body: EMAIL_BODY,
    name: EMAIL_FROM,
    attachments: [blob],
  });
}
```